# ElasticSearch Java API Client - Send already serialized data and avoid serialization

Tags: java, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-client

I have a Kafka Topic wit JSON data. Now im trying to send those JSON strings to an ES topic using the new "Java API Client" (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api-client/7.17/index.html), but im running into a parser exception:

```
co.elastic.clients.elasticsearch._types.ElasticsearchException: [es/index] failed: [mapper_parsing_exception] failed to parse
at co.elastic.clients.transport.rest_client.RestClientTransport.getHighLevelResponse(RestClientTransport.java:281)
at co.elastic.clients.transport.rest_client.RestClientTransport.performRequest(RestClientTransport.java:147)
at co.elastic.clients.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchClient.index(ElasticsearchClient.java:953)
```

This exception occurs in the last line of the following code:

```
final IndexRequest<String> request =
          new IndexRequest.Builder<String>()
              .index("myIndex")
              .id(String.valueOf(UUID.randomUUID()))
              .document(consumerRecord.value()) //already serialized json data
              .build();
elasticsearchClient.index(request);
```

As far as I understand this exception occurs, because the ES client tries to serialize the data im providing, which is already serialized, resulting in a malformed JSON string.

Is there anyway to get around this and just send simple JSON strings? Also I believe this was possible with the earlier "Low Level Java Library", right? And yes, I know there are ways to allow communication between Kafka and ES without writing a Consumer.

Thanks for any hints.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use a `JacksonJsonpMapper` when creating your `ElasticsearchTransport`, you can use a custom `PreserializedJson` class to send already-serialized JSON.

```
ElasticsearchTransport transport = new RestClientTransport(
    createLowLevelRestClient(), // supply your own!
    new JacksonJsonpMapper()
);

ElasticsearchClient client = new ElasticsearchClient(transport);

IndexResponse response = client.index(indexReq -> indexReq
    .index("my-index")
    .id("docId")
    .document(new PreserializedJson("{\"foo\":\"bar\"}"))
);
System.out.println(response);
```

Here is the source for `PreserializedJson`:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonGenerator;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializerProvider;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.annotation.JsonSerialize;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.StdSerializer;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;

import static java.util.Objects.requireNonNull;

@JsonSerialize(using = PreserializedJson.Serializer.class)
public class PreserializedJson {
  private final String value;

  public PreserializedJson(String value) {
    this.value = requireNonNull(value);
  }

  public PreserializedJson(byte[] value) {
    this(new String(value, StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
  }

  public static class Serializer extends StdSerializer<PreserializedJson> {
    public Serializer() {
      super(PreserializedJson.class);
    }

    @Override
    public void serialize(PreserializedJson value, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException {
      gen.writeRaw(value.value);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, even though it's been some time I dug up the project and tried your approach. It's working as advertised! :)

Comment: @wolle271 I updated this answer to use a custom `PerserializedJson` class instead of Jackson's `SerializedString`. After some more testing, it looks like using `SerializedString` didn't really work, since it wraps the argument in a "value" node and serializes the argument as a String.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by substituting "Java API Client" (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api-client/current/introduction.html) with "Java Low Level Rest Client" (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api-client/current/java-rest-low.html).

This Library allows sending of arbitrary JSON-Strings to ES:

```
  final Request request = new Request("POST", "/twitter/_doc");
  request.setJsonEntity(record.value());
  restClient.performRequest(request);
```

Answer (score 0):

With the new API Client, you can natively insert raw json into it.
As specified here : [Using raw json data](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api-client/current/indexing.html#_using_raw_json_data)

```
IndexRequest<JsonData> request = IndexRequest.of(i -> i
    .index("logs")
    .withJson(input)
);
```